# App crashing android studio after moving project folder

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Three weeks ago, I decided to move my project from the downloads folder on my Mac to my desktop. After moving the project, I realized that I wasn't able to even see anything from the project. So I decided to move the project back into the downloads folder when it originally was in, and I was able to check my project again but unfortunately I am not able to run the project on my phone and I am getting a strange error message that I am not able to find a solution for on the internet. I will show you the error message and some XML code of the activity as well.

XML code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="427dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_view_message"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/channel_spinner"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.162" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/check_button"
        android:layout_width="157dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:text="@string/home_button_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/channel_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.418" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mychannels/com.example.mychannels.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1926)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6990)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Build.gradle (app level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mychannels"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha05'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: please post your `build.gradle` app-level

Comment: you are getting error over here `<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` .Have you  added   `BottomNavigationView` library ?

Comment: check you backgroundcolor and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214297/10967323) one also check dependancy.

Comment: remove android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searches about my problem and after trying many times to fix it, I re tried to delete the android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" statement from the XML code, the app opened and ran without any problems on my phone. I tried to do so the first time when I opened this discussion but it didn't work. Thank you for helping me to solve my problem!

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate caches/restart  & try to import it. File -> new -> import project

Comment: Invalidating the cashes and restarting the project didn't help me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha1' In your app gradle file. Just add this gradle inside 
dependencies { } black and sync your project. Now, this error should be removed and aproject will run successfully.

Comment: I tried to add this implementation but I got an error message saying that this implementation was not able to be resolved when I tried to sync the project after adding this implementation

Comment: Can you please paste the error here for more understanding?

Comment: This is the error that I am getting: `ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha1
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app`

Comment: Just make sure you have google() center in your project level gradle file like this 

 repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

Comment: And also Try with File-> Sync project with Gradle file option from the top bar of the android studio.

Comment: I checked the project level gradle file and I found google() and Jcenter() in the repositories as you mentioned, after that I retried syncing the project using the top bar of android studio but I still have the same error.

Comment: add    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' instead of  com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently and the only thing that truly helped me open a project after having moved it to another folder was to completely delete the `build` folder (that one located inside `app` folder) before launching Android Studio. Tested on Android Studio 4.1.3 / Windows 10.